# When a phone call comes , does the accelerometer stops reading in Android phones?

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am developing an app which writes accelerometer reading in a file every second. My android phone does  not has a service provider so I cant check it.

When a call comes, will the accelerometer stop recording ??

Comment: did you put the accelerometer at work in a service in a thread ?

Comment: Not in a service ... But in A UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not if it's running in a `Service` or on a `AsyncTask`. When you are running the accelerometer on the UI `Thread` it will be stopped by the `Activity`s `onPause()` method but if you run it on a different thread it will not stop.

Comment: I am running it on UI thread. If I dont use the onPause() method, will it stop ?

Comment: onPause() is used by the OS. Don't run it on the UI thread, that's just bad practice

Comment: If this is critical for your app to keep measuring stuff with accelerometer ==> background service in its own thread. Lot of documentation on it.

Comment: Glad to be of service :)